# In a jquery slider, which image is showing?

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I found some code for a very simple jquery slider.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($)
{

    var slideCount = $('#slider ul li').length;
    var slideWidth = $('#slider ul li').width();
    var slideHeight = $('#slider ul li').height();
    var sliderUlWidth = slideCount * slideWidth;

    $('#slider').css({ width: slideWidth, height: slideHeight });

    $('#slider ul').css({ width: sliderUlWidth, marginLeft: -slideWidth });

    $('#slider ul li:last-child').prependTo('#slider ul');

    function moveLeft()
    {
        $('#slider ul').animate({
            left: +slideWidth
        }, 200, function ()
        {
            $('#slider ul li:last-child').prependTo('#slider ul');
            $('#slider ul').css('left', '');
        });
    };

    function moveRight()
    {
        $('#slider ul').animate({
            left: -slideWidth
        }, 200, function ()
        {
            $('#slider ul li:first-child').appendTo('#slider ul');
            $('#slider ul').css('left', '');
        });
    };

    $('a.control_prev').click(function ()
    {
        moveLeft();
    });

    $('a.control_next').click(function ()
    {
        moveRight();
    });

});
```

The html is:

```
<div id="slider">
<a href="#" class="control_next">></a>
<a href="#" class="control_prev"><</a>
<ul id="picList" runat="server">
<li><img alt="" src="/Images/Piano.jpg"><p class="caption">Piano</p></li>
<li><img alt="" src="/Images/Violin.jpg"><p class="caption">Violin</p></li>
<li><img alt="" src="/Images/Flute.jpg"><p class="caption">Flute</p></li>
<li><img alt="" src="/Images/Oboe.jpg"><p class="caption">Oboe</p></li>
</ul>
</div>
<div id="dvPiano" style="display:none">Description here</div>
<div id="dvViolin" style="display:none">Description here</div>
<div id="dvFlute" style="display:none">Description here</div>
<div id="dvOboe" style="display:none">Description here</div>
```

There are dozens of images - which ones are displayed in the slider is determined in the code behind. There could be 10 images in the slider and I have no way of knowing which one may be first.

My question is: When someone clicks to go left or right - and moveLeft() or moveRight() is called ... how can I determine which description div (below the slider) to show? How do I know that the image for 'flute' is currently showing and show 'dvflute'?

Comment: One option can be while generating img tags, add an attribute which hold the position, and then the by script display the first one, rest can be done based on the attribute value +1, and -1

Comment: Thanks for your reply ... I did think of that but, if I do that ... say I have moved to the img with an attribute of 3 ... how do I know which description div to display? I will have, say, 10 divs holding descriptions - I need to be able to say 'if the image that is showing is Violin.jpg, show dvViolin etc.

Comment: what will be the issue if we give the same attribute to div and img, in this way both will be coupled, so if we have the image index known, then the div will also be having same index.

Comment: I have, for example, a maximum of 20 pictures. Each picture has an accompanying div. The divs, as it were, are hard coded on the page - all 20 of them, with visibility set to none. But which pictures are in the slider is generated dynamically. So, I might have 2 pictures - imgFlute and imgBassoon - and I need to show the appropriate dv. On another view of the page, there might be 8 images etc. How do I know which image is currently displaying in the slider? If I know it is 'imgViolin' I can easily show 'dvViolin'. I can't work out which image is showing.